# understanding the proof of Sylvester's law of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> [image]
>
> [image]

This proof comes from Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Spence, Insel. I don't understand the last step in this proof, which I highlight with a purple line.  I understand that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 H(v_j, v_j) = \sum_{j=p+1}^r  H(v_j, v_j) $ since $a_i = 0$ for $i \le p$ and $H(v_i, v_i) = 0 $ for $i>r$. But, why $b_i =0$ for $i=1, ... , p$?

I appreciate if you give some help, and I apologize to ask you for reading a long proof.

Comment: Should the final sum not run (in two parts) from $1$ to $q$ and $r+1$ to $n$?

Comment: My understanding of this proof is that $H(w_i, w_i) = 0$ for $i > r$  and $b_i =0$ for $q+1 \le i \le r$ (as stated in the proof). So should the sum run from $1$ to $q$? but why does it run from $p+1$ to $r$?

Answer (score 2):

The last term should not be $\sum_{j=p+1}^{r} b_j^2 H(w_j,w_j)$ but rather it should be

$\sum_{j=1}^{q} b_j^2 H(w_j,w_j) + \sum_{j=r+1}^{n} b_j^2 H(w_j,w_j)$, which is non-negative.